# python integration with azure gremlin not working

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to mimic as mentioned in [GIT](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-python-getting-started.git).

I almost commented everything, and just trying to run simply

```
g.V().count()
```

my connection details are correct, and matched to documentation...

I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PrasaRak\OneDrive\gremlin_azure_function\connect.py", line 193, in <module>
    count_vertices(client)
  File "c:\Users\PrasaRak\OneDrive\gremlin_azure_function\connect.py", line 116, in count_vertices
    callback = client.submit(_gremlin_count_vertices)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\client.py", line 127, in submit
    return self.submitAsync(message, bindings=bindings, request_options=request_options).result()
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\client.py", line 148, in submitAsync
    return conn.write(message)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\connection.py", line 55, in write
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\connection.py", line 45, in connect
    self._transport.connect(self._url, self._headers)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\tornado\transport.py", line 40, in connect
    self._ws = self._loop.run_sync(
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 576, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\simple_httpclient.py", line 269, in run
    stream = yield self.tcp_client.connect(
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpclient.py", line 232, in connect
    af, addr, stream = yield connector.start(connect_timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpclient.py", line 87, in start
    self.try_connect(iter(self.primary_addrs))
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpclient.py", line 104, in try_connect
    stream, future = self.connect(af, addr)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpclient.py", line 276, in _create_stream
    return stream, stream.connect(addr)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 1325, in connect
    self._add_io_state(self.io_loop.WRITE)
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 1157, in _add_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 83, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_writer(
  File "C:\Users\PrasaRak\Miniconda3\envs\learn-gremlin\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 507, in add_writer
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i got the answer.

issue was with python 3.8 & Tornado compatibility, when it comes to asyncio.

more info is at this [link](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2608)

fix was to add following line in tornado/platform/asyncio.py

```
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())  # python-3.8.0a4
```

Comment: You just saved me from a massive headache, thank you!